# Where do assembly instruction "Intel group" categories originate?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, x86-16, machine-code

During development of my fork of an 86-DOS application, [lDebug](https://pushbx.org/ecm/web/#projects-ldebug), I came across categories of instructions referred to as "Intel groups". Specifically, group means something related to a set of instructions using the same 1 or 2 opcode bytes, differentiated by the `/r` field of the ModR/M byte.

The "Intel group" categories go all the way back to FreeDOS Debug 0.95 released in 1997, and can be seen [in that revision of my fddebug repo](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/fddebug/file/b237abb3a356/MKTABLES.C#l338):

```
/*
 *  Here are the tables for the main processor groups.
 */

struct {
    int seq;    /* sequence number of the group */
    int info;   /* which group number it is */
}
    grouptab[]  = {
        {0x80, GROUP(1)},   /* Intel group 1 */
        {0x81, GROUP(1)},
        {0x83, GROUP(2)},
        {0xd0, GROUP(3)},   /* Intel group 2 */
        {0xd1, GROUP(3)},
        {0xd2, GROUP(4)},
        {0xd3, GROUP(4)},
        {0xc0, GROUP(5)},   /* Intel group 2a */
        {0xc1, GROUP(5)},
        {0xf6, GROUP(6)},   /* Intel group 3 */
        {0xf7, GROUP(6)},
        {0xff, GROUP(7)},   /* Intel group 5 */
        {SPARSE_BASE + 0x00, GROUP(8)},     /* Intel group 6 */
        {SPARSE_BASE + 0x01, GROUP(9)}};    /* Intel group 7 */

/* #define  NGROUPS 9 (this was done above) */

struct {    /* sparse groups */
    int seq;    /* sequence number of the group */
    int info;   /* which group number it is */
}
    sp_grouptab[]   = {
        {0xfe, SGROUP(1)},      /* Intel group 4 */
        {SPARSE_BASE+0xba, SGROUP(2)},  /* Intel group 8 */
        {SPARSE_BASE+0xc7, SGROUP(3)},  /* Intel group 9 */
        {0x8f, SGROUP(4)},      /* Not an Intel group */
        {0xc6, SGROUP(5)},      /* Not an Intel group */
        {0xc7, SGROUP(5)}};

/* #define  NSGROUPS    5 (this was done above) */
```

I cannot find anything about the "Intel group" categorisation. An exact web search like ["intel group 2a"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22intel+group+2a%22) only turns up a repo of the same application. Broader searches don't turn up anything matching the use in these comments.

At no time have I found any "group" categories in the Intel manuals I have read, either. For example, [this 486 manual](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/components/intel/80486/i486_Processor_Programmers_Reference_Manual_1990.pdf) doesn't seem to list groups in its instruction set reference.

Comment: The [sandpile site](https://www.sandpile.org/x86/opc_grp.htm) uses the same grouping.  As do the intel manuals (see Tbl. A-6 in volume 2D of the Intel Software Developer's Manual).

Comment: My 1993 copy of the *Intel486™ Microprocessor Family Programmer's Reference Manual* shows these groups, up to and including group 8, in the opcode map starting at page A-3. Likewise the 1990 copy of the *386™ DX Programmer's Reference Manual*, also starting at page A-3.

Comment: @njuffa: Indeed, the link I showed also contains the opcode map on page A-4 (page 784 of the PDF). The groups are referred to as "GrpX".

Comment: Group 9 was added in the 1995 *Pentium Family Developer's Manual, Volume 3: Architecture and Programming Manual*, page A-9, and contained solely the `CMPXCH 8BMq` instruction at that time. I cannot find any groups mentioned in the 80286 manual, so presumably the "group" concept was introduced with the 386, i.e. 32-bit architecture.

Comment: These groups have always been in Appendix A of the manual -- looking at the [latest one](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-sdm.html), it has groups 1 - 17

Comment: @njuffa The "group" concept was already present in the 8086 manual.

Comment: @SepRoland I stand corrected in part. After some searching, I found the figure in the 8086 manual that you are likely referring to and it does show "Grp1" and "Grp2" along with "Immed" and "Shift". This, however, does not seem identical to the group numbering scheme from the question, which first appeared in the 386 manual, best I can tell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My 1980 copy of the "8086/8087/8088 MACRO ASSEMBLY LANGUAGE REFERENCE MANUAL for 8086-Based Development Systems" already introduced the 'group' concept albeit still somewhat incomplete.

Opcodes 80h-83h and D0h-D3h could be linked to the named groups "immed" and "Shift" because the instructions that belong to the group have a  clear common characteristic.
Not so for the opcodes F6h-F7h and FEh-FFh, so they chose a more universal approach and gave these groups the generic name "Grp " suffixed by a number.

Some 6 years later, the 386 manual took another shot at naming these existing groups and decided to rename the old "Grp 1" as "Unary Grp3", and the old "Grp 2" as "Indirct Grp5". Several new groups were added and once again the heterogeneous nature of these groups made the engineers fall back on generic naming.

**8086**

| opcode | group | 000 | 001 | 010 | 011 | 100 | 101 | 110 | 111 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 80h-83h | immed | ADD | OR | ADC | SBB | AND | SUB | XOR | CMP |
| D0h-D3h | Shift | ROL | ROR | RCL | RCR | SHL SAL | SHR | - | SAR |
| F6h-F7h | Grp 1 | TEST | - | NOT | NEG | MUL | IMUL | DIV | IDIV |
| FEh-FFh | Grp 2 | INC | DEC | CALL | CALL | JMP | JMP | PUSH | - |

**80386**

| opcode | group | 000 | 001 | 010 | 011 | 100 | 101 | 110 | 111 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 80h-83h | Immediate Grpl | ADD | OR | ADC | SBB | AND | SUB | XOR | CMP |
| C0h-C1h, D0h-D3h | Shift Grp2 | ROL | ROR | RCL | RCR | SHL | SHR |  | SAR |
| F6h-F7h | Unary Grp3 | TEST |  | NOT | NEG | MUL | IMUL | DIV | IDIV |
| FEh | INC/DEC Grp4 | INC | DEC |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| FFh | Indirct Grp5 | INC | DEC | CALL | CALL | JMP | JMP | PUSH |  |
| 0Fh,00h | Grp6 | SLDT | STR | LLDT | LTR | VERR | VERW |  |  |
| 0Fh,01h | Grp7 | SGDT | SIDT | LGDT | LIDT | SMSW |  | LMSW |  |
| 0Fh,BAh | Grp-8 |  |  |  |  | BT | BTS | BTR | BTC |